How can I align textures of 2 objects?
I have a wall and a door with same dimensions but different UVs so it doesn't line up when put next to each other.
I'm trying to move the UVs up and down but that is hard to align. Is there a better way ?


Hello, maybe unwrap the 2 object at the same time then align the UVs in the UV Editor?

no it didnt work maybe the texture isnt tiled but your answere is smart

could you please pack your texture and share your file?
